# How do I load data from a record into multiple edittexts in android studio?

Tags: sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I'm currently working through my A Level computer science controlled assessment, and am making an application designed to help Scout Leaders manage their group.  This is my first time working in Java, SQLite, Android Studio and XML so I've run into a few problems along the way.  At this point in time, I'm in the process of creating a login system, part of which involves editing login details.  I was wondering if there's a way of loading multiple values from one record into different EditTexts at once, so the user only needs to edit the already-existing username and password, rather than type it in again with a slight edit?  Thanks in advance.  I didn't think it necessary to include any code in this question, as I'm only looking for an example, however if it would help please don't hesitate to ask - I just couldn't find a guide on this anywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You retrieve the data into a **Cursor** via a query that selects the required columns.
2. You then **move** to the appropriate row (record) in the Cursor (probably the first and only row).
3. For each **EditText** you set the text, using the **setText** method with the data from the respective column using an appropriate **`get????`** method passing the column offset to the method (*e.g. `your_cursor.getString(<the_column_offset>)`*).

   1. *Rather than calculating and hard coding an offset, it is more reliable and flexible to use the `getColumnIndex(<the_column_name_as_string>)` method.*
4. After all have been set you then close the **Cursor**

   - Note  and  would be replaced with respective values specific to the App.

Comment: Apologies for not getting back to you, I've been at a university interview - I'll give it a go now.